# Performing number clamping for only numeric template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class val {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_value, m_min, m_max;;
public:
    val(T value, T min, T max) : m_value(std::make_shared<T>(value)), m_min(std::make_shared<T>(min)), m_max(std::make_shared<T>(max)) {}
    val(T value) : m_value(std::make_shared<T>(value)), m_min(nullptr), m_max(nullptr) {}
public:
    operator T() {
        return *this->m_value;
    }

    val& operator=(const T& other) {
        *this->m_value = other;

        return *this;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> minimum() {
        return this->m_min;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> maximum() {
        return this->m_max;
    }
};
```

Used as such:

```
auto i = val(5);
auto f = val(64.f);
auto f_clamped = val(64.f, 0.f, 128.f);
```

My desired functionality is to have this operation go as such:

```
auto f_clamped = val(64.f, 0.f, 128.f);
f_clamped = 32.f; // all good
f_clamped = 200.f; // f_clamped is now 128.f
```

I tried implementing this in the equals (=) operator of the class as such:

```
val& operator=(const T& other) {
        T ret = other;

        if (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value) {
            if (this->m_min && this->m_max) {
                T min = *this->m_min;
                T max = *this->m_max;

                if (ret > max)
                    ret = max;
                if (ret < min)
                    ret = min;
            }
        }

        *this->m_value = other;

        return *this;
    }
```

But this doesn't work, because T, from the compiler's perspective, cannot be assumed to be an arithmetic value.

How do I assert that T is an arithmetic value so that I can do arithmetic operations on it?

Is something like this okay?

````
    template<
        typename T,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::value
    >
    val& operator=(const T& other) {
        T ret = other;

        if (this->m_min && this->m_max) {
            T min = *this->m_min;
            T max = *this->m_max;

            if (ret > max)
                ret = max;
            if (ret < min)
                ret = min;
        }


        *this->m_value = other;

        return *this;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that `*this->m_value = other;` should be `*this->m_value = ret;`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yeah I typed this up quickly for the post. That's not relevant to the question but definitely my mistake

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that shows the problem you are having, please can you also explain more clearly exactly what your problem is

Comment: Those shared_ptr seems strange, `std::optional` for bounds seems more appropriate.

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<T>::value)` won't hurt. but a `static_assert` in the class seems more appropriate, as, if you remove clamping, your class has no longer a purpose...

Comment: Maybe off topic. But are you somehow reinventing ````std::clamp````? Please see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, i changed it to `std::optional<std::pair<T, T>> m_minmax;`. Can you show me how you'd use `static_assert` in this case?
@ArminMontigny No, I'm not. Clamping is not the main feature of this class.

Comment: `template<typename T>
class val { static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Class only usable with arithmetic types"); /*..*/};`. but traits `is_arithmetic` might not be the more appropriate, it seems you want "ordered" types.

Comment: *"But this doesn't work"*. When? Provide MCVE.

Comment: @Jarod42 Disregard my previous statement ("but this doesn't work"). It works, using the example I provided in the bottom of the post. T can be any value, and is intended to be used with all types, even non arithmetic types. The goal here was to only apply clamping to arithmetic types. Sorry for the confusion.